# auto Complete textview set hidden value and visible text android

Tags: android

Im try to build auto Complete textview in android, and its work fine, but my problem is I need to get a value was related for item was selected, I mean

we have schools

abc, bbt, ccce, ddde

abc  have id = 1, and number_of_students = 30

bbt  have id = 2, and number_of_students = 20 students

ccce have id = 3, and number_of_students = 50 students

ddde have id = 4, and number_of_students = 40 students

when user write in text view **abc**, and select it, I need to get **id** and **number_of_students**, not only abc text,

I mean in html we have `<option value="1">text<option>`, when select it, we get a 1, not a text, is there option in android to set text and I get a value not a text

thanks a lot.

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.schoolsAutoComp);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);

    textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
            //pos is the position of the selected item
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), COUNTRIES[pos], Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
```

Final Solution:

```
        textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
            String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            int pos2 = -1;

            for (int i = 0; i < COUNTRIES.length; i++) {
                if (COUNTRIES[i].equals(selection)) {
                    pos2 = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Position " + pos2); //check it now in Logcat
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry mate, I mean in html we have <option value="1">text<option>, when select it, we get a 1, not a text ..thats I mean

Comment: Show your code for COUNTRIES.

Comment: Thanks you barq for help, and sorry to late for this response, Im found a solution dependence of your idea, thanks  a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos, long id)
      {
         //pos is the position of the selected item
      }
    });
```

Comment: thanks a lot mate, Im get a position, but the problem is give me a position dependence of current list option (dependence of letters was set by user) not for original array .. is there solution ^_^

Comment: Just store the number of students in an array such that the index matches your desired text and then access the array by the position/id.

Comment: Yup, I know that mate, But I mean, the "pos" was i received, is the position of order in list view when user write some letters, not a position for an original array ... the abc school in original array was index 5, if i write a the pos received 2, when write ab a pos received 0 ...

Comment: Then map the position in the array to position in the list.

Comment: I think , I must now do easy solution, I will get a text was selected and then compare the string with array, if i do this, I can get all of option, Thanks a lot mate,

Comment: Show your code for the selection. I don't understand why the id in Array and View don't match. Maybe View position stars with 0, so you can just add 1 and get the right string?

Comment: yup, me too 
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);
        textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
                //pos is the position of the selected item
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), COUNTRIES[pos], Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
     toast.show();
            }
        });

Comment: Edit your answer and add that code. It's impossible to read as a comment.

Comment: what is there are duplicate names in array